# How can I make For loops with an If statement more efficient when iterating over rows in VBa?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

I have a For loop nested inside another For loop which iterates over every row in a spreadsheet.

The nested for loop below checks the current row and then loops over every row in the spreadsheet to see if it matches the If statement criteria. If so, it changes a bool to True and exits the nested loop.

This method takes far too long. The spreadsheet is 1000 rows x 27 columns and will take forever to run through on the small PC I'm using.

The Code:

```
    Sub Check_Errors()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim duplicateData As Boolean

    Set Data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data") 'Worksheet with Raw data
    Set Errors = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Errors") 'Where any flagged rows are copied to.

    x = 2
    lastRow = Data.Cells(Data.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    duplicateData = False

'Copies the headings from Data worksheet to Error worksheet
    For j = 1 To 26
        Errors.Cells(1, j).Value = Data.Cells(1, j).Value
    Next j

    Errors.Cells(1, 27).Value = "Error Type"

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        wrongSpeciality = False



            For j = 2 To 300
                If ((Data.Cells(i, 19) < Data.Cells(j, 19) + (Data.Cells(j, 20) / 1440) + (Data.Cells(j, 21) / 1440) _
                And Data.Cells(i, 19) >= Data.Cells(j, 19)) _
                Or _
                (Data.Cells(i, 19) + (Data.Cells(i, 20) / 1440) + (Data.Cells(i, 21) / 1440) <= Data.Cells(j, 19) + (Data.Cells(j, 20) / 1440) + (Data.Cells(j, 21) / 1440) _
                And Data.Cells(i, 19) + (Data.Cells(i, 20) / 1440) + (Data.Cells(i, 21) / 1440) > Data.Cells(j, 19))) _
         _
                And Data.Cells(i, 18) = Data.Cells(j, 18) _
                And Data.Cells(i, 22) = Data.Cells(j, 22) _
                And Not i = j Then

                    duplicateData = True
                    Exit For

                End If
            Next j

'If true then copy flagged row to Error worksheet and add additional column with reason row was flagged.   
        If duplicateData Then

            For j = 1 To 26
                Errors.Cells(x, j).Value = Data.Cells(i, j).Value
            Next j
            Errors.Cells(x, 27).Value = "Time overlapping"
            x = x + 1
        End If

    Next i
```

The Data

ClinicalTime and AdminTime are in minutes and need to be divided by 1440 before being added to Time to get the correct finish time.

James sees someone at 13:00 on the 12th Jan and finishes at 13:30. But it also shows he saw someone at 13:25 which isn't possible as he was with someone during that time.

The above code will change `duplicateData` to True for both these rows, but will take a very long time to do so over thousands of these instances.

```
Columns 18        19     20             21            22
        Date      Time   ClinicalTime   AdminTime     Clinician
        12/01/18  13:00  20             10            James
        12/01/18  13:25  10             20            James
        12/01/18  14:30  40              0            James
        14/01/18  10:00  20             20            Samantha
```

Worth noting is a finish time can be the same as a start time, so James could see a patient at 11:00, finish at 11:30, and have start time for the next patient at 11:30 and there would be no need to flag these two.

Comment: Store the data from the excel sheet into and array and then work with the array. That will be much much faster :)

Comment: If you expect more than that comment you should include your relevant code since it is incomplete and no [mcve]. Always include declaration/initialization of your variables too.

Comment: Thanks @Pᴇʜ. Hopefully the code I've provided now will help further.

Comment: Is the data sorted by any of these columns? If so by which? Are we allowed to sort it? If we could assume sorted data that would be a benefit for developing a better algorithm.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ The data can be sorted in any order

Comment: @WillacyMe Sorry for asking again. Does that mean we are allowed to re-sort it or does that mean it is not sorted when you get it.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ No worries. It's not sorted when I get it and can be re-sorted to any order. Once the flagged rows are copied to the Error worksheet it's that data that is then analysed and re-sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the following data:

[image]

Sort it by BOTH:

- Column V (Clinician) A … Z
- AND Column W (START) low … high

I added 3 columns W, X and Y (you can use others). Formulas are:

- Column W: `=R:R+S:S` (adds together start date and time)
- Column X: `=R:R+S:S+T:T/1440+U:U/1440` (calculates end date/time)
- Y2 (and copy down): `=IF(AND(V2=V1,W2<X1),"Overlapping","-")`

Then filter by Column Y (Overlapping) and you have your data.

**How does the formula work?**
The formula checks for each row if the Clinician is the same as in the row before (otherwise it is the first row of that Clinician which can never be a overlap). Then it checks if the START is *before* the END of the row before. If so it is overlapping, otherwise not.

Note that this method works only on properly sorted data.

---

If using formulas does not meet your needs then the idea of this method could also be used in VBA. This should be *much* faster because only minimal amount of data would be needed to test and you need to loop through all rows only once.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CheckForOverlappings()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    Dim wsErrors As Worksheet
    Set wsErrors = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Errors")

    Dim LastDataRow As Long
    LastDataRow = wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim LastErrorRow As Long
    LastErrorRow = 2

    'sort data by …
    With wsData.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        '… field Clinician
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("V2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        '… field Date
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("R2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        '… field Time
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("S2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        .SetRange Range("1:" & LastDataRow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With


    'write headers for error sheet
    wsErrors.Cells(1, 1).Resize(ColumnSize:=26).Value = wsData.Cells(1, 1).Resize(ColumnSize:=26).Value
    wsErrors.Cells(1, 27).Value = "Error Type"

    'read relevant data into array
    Dim arrData As Variant
    arrData = wsData.Range(wsData.Cells(1, 18), wsData.Cells(LastDataRow, 22))

    'initialize start/enddate with first data row (= row 2)
    Dim StartDate As Date
    StartDate = arrData(2, 1) + arrData(2, 2)
    Dim EndDate As Date
    EndDate = StartDate + arrData(2, 3) / 1440 + arrData(2, 4) / 1440

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 3 To UBound(arrData, 1) 'loop from data row 2 (= row 3) we used data row 1 in initialization already
        'determine start date of current row
        StartDate = arrData(iRow, 1) + arrData(iRow, 2)

        If arrData(iRow, 1) = arrData(iRow - 1, 1) And StartDate < EndDate Then 'check same cinician and overlapping
            'copy column 1 … 26 to error sheet
            wsErrors.Cells(LastErrorRow, 1).Resize(ColumnSize:=26).Value = wsData.Cells(iRow, 1).Resize(ColumnSize:=26).Value

            LastErrorRow = LastErrorRow + 1
        End If

        'remember end date of current row (for comparison with next row)
        EndDate = StartDate + arrData(iRow, 3) / 1440 + arrData(iRow, 4) / 1440
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing! I would prefer it in Vba as the loop checks other conditions which are copied into the Error worksheet as well. I'm not too confident with arrays as yet so this is a perfect answer for me to learn and implement. Thanks so much! I'll report back when and if I can get it to work successfully myself.

Comment: Actually using arrays of values is very easy and works like working with `Cells(row, column)` too. If you read data into an array like `arr = Range("A1:B10").Value` you can use it like `arr(row, column)` as you did before with `Cells()`. Advantage of arrays is that they are much faster because they only contain the values while the cells also contain formatting stuff etc.

Comment: Where you have `If arrData(iRow, 1) = arrData(iRow, 1)` should it not be `If arrData(iRow, 1) = arrData(iRow+1, 1)`, otherwise it's checking if it's the same as itself?

Comment: @WillacyMe Ehhm yes, of course that's wrong. But it must be *minus 1* `arrData(iRow - 1, 1)` because it needs to compare to the row *before* and not to the next row. It must always compare the actual row `iRow` against the data in the row *before*!

Comment: I've implemented you solution to great success. But would like to note I needed both rows of overlapping data. For this I added a PreviousEndDate and NextStartDate variables and the formula looked at the row below as well as the row above.

Comment: Another note worth mentioning is if 15/02/18 15:00 added half an hour of activity and compared it to another row that had a start date/time of 15/02/18 15:30, excel would see these two dates as different. This was corrected by using `If DateDiff("s" PreviousEndDate, StartDate) = 0 Then`